# Method 'HttpRequestBase.GetBufferlessInputStream' not found when using owin auth on mono

Tags: asp.net, mono, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I deployed a Asp.Net Web API project onto my CentOS server running mono 4.3.0 (compiled from mono-4.2.1.36 branch released 2 days ago). I built the project using VS2015 enpty web api template and added owin authentication in an attempt to get a web api working with authentication using bearer tokens.

I'm hosting the project on apache server using mod_mono.

When running the project locally on my windows machine, everything works perfectly. On Linux, when I send a http POST to the /token endpoint, the server returns a 200 OK, but without any response payload (which would include the bearer token the client needs to authenticate subsequent requests). At the same time, the server logs an exception (following).

```
System.MissingMethodException: Method 'HttpRequestBase.GetBufferlessInputStream' not found.
  at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.CallStreams.InputStream.get_Stream () <0xb0e339b8 + 0x00013> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.CallStreams.DelegatingStream.get_CanRead () <0xb0e45eb0 + 0x00013> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor (System.IO.Stream stream, System.Text.Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean leaveOpen) <0xb0e5d790 + 0x0005f> in <filename unknown>:0
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.StreamReader:.ctor (System.IO.Stream,System.Text.Encoding,bool,int,bool)
  at Microsoft.Owin.OwinRequest+<ReadFormAsync>d__0.MoveNext () <0xb0e33510 + 0x000f3> in <filename unknown>:0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <0xb0e34a68 + 0x0002b> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0xb0e346d0 + 0x000bb> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0xb0e34588 + 0x0007f> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0xb270df98 + 0x00033> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () <0xb270e1d0 + 0x00017> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthAuthorizationServerHandler+<InvokeTokenEndpointAsync>d__22.MoveNext () <0xb0e2f118 + 0x00463> in <filename unknown>:0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <0xb0e34a68 + 0x0002b> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0xb0e346d0 + 0x000bb> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0xb0e34588 + 0x0007f> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0xb270df98 + 0x00033> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () <0xb270df70 + 0x00013> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthAuthorizationServerHandler+<InvokeAsync>d__0.MoveNext () <0xb270e790 + 0x007a7> in <filename unknown>:0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <0xb0e34a68 + 0x0002b> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0xb0e346d0 + 0x000bb> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0xb0e34588 + 0x0007f> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0xb270df98 + 0x00033> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () <0xb270f5b0 + 0x00013> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationMiddleware`1+<Invoke>d__0[TOptions].MoveNext () <0xb270b2a0 + 0x0030f> in <filename unknown>:0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <0xb0e34a68 + 0x0002b> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0xb0e346d0 + 0x000bb> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0xb0e34588 + 0x0007f> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0xb270df98 + 0x00033> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () <0xb270df70 + 0x00013> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContextStage+<RunApp>d__5.MoveNext () <0xb270aa98 + 0x00173> in <filename unknown>:0
```

After googling I found that this exception has been fixed in another namespace, but note this originates in  Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.

Is there a workaround to get rid of the exception, and does anyone have information on if that exception is the reason for the behavior I'm facing or is there something else I can try in order to get bearer token based authentication working?

In my AuthorizationServerProvider I implement the following methods:
(also, when running on Linux the response headers do not include Access-Control-Allow-Origin like they do on Windows)

```
public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
{
  context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });
  context.Validated();
  return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
}

public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{
    //check credentials

    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.UserName)); //etc

    var props = new AuthenticationProperties(new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
       { "as:client_id", (context.ClientId == null) ? string.Empty : context.ClientId },
       { "userName", context.UserName }
    });

    var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, props);
    context.Validated(ticket);
}

public override Task TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> property in context.Properties.Dictionary)
    {
        context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add(property.Key, property.Value);
    }

    return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
}
```

My Startup.cs looks like this:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    ConfigureOAuth(app);

    HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration(); 
    config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
    WebApiConfig.Register(config); 

    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());

    app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);  
    app.UseWebApi(config);
}

public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
    {
        AllowInsecureHttp = true,
        TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
        AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15),
        Provider = new BoaAuthorizationServerProvider(),

        RefreshTokenProvider = new BoaRefreshTokenProvider(),
        ApplicationCanDisplayErrors = true,
    };
    // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
    app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthServerOptions);
}
```

---

EDIT:

Some more information on this:

I tried the old remove-the-problematic-dll -trick, and I no longer get that exception, but however I do get a 500 Internal Server Error, when sending a http POST to the token endpoint (the same that works on windows).

This is the exception:

```
System.Web.HttpException
Method 'POST' is not allowed when accessing file '/webapitest/token'

Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.
Details: Error processing request.
Exception stack trace:
   at System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest (System.Web.HttpContext context, System.AsyncCallback callback, System.Object state) in <filename unknown>:line 0
   at System.Web.HttpApplication+<Pipeline>c__Iterator1.MoveNext () in <filename unknown>:line 0
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.Tick () in <filename unknown>:line 0
```

Note the Startup configuration above, is there anything there that mono does not support? If not, this seems like either a configuration problem or a bug in mono as someone previously commented that they get the same MissingMethodException about GetBufferlessInputStream that happens on Ubuntu. That comment has then been removed.

Answer (score 0):

This error is still reproduced on mono builds downloaded from official repos(seems like correct GetBufferlessInputStream & GetBufferedInputStream were implemented in that commit:
[303d876370017774445c71736cf34e851e5cb037](https://github.com/mono/mono/commit/303d876370017774445c71736cf34e851e5cb037)).

The easiest way for me was to update dependent libraries from nightlybuild repo(not need to compile whole project and to update only required libraries for disk space saving). 
Update instructions for Debian:

```
echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian nightly main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-nightly.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libmono-system-net-http-webrequest4.0-cil
```

(any other libmono http library should work too, list of needed packages will be composed automatically)